# Ruby: How to get current main project working directory's

Tags: ruby

I need to get the main project working directory, for example I have a project folder structure like,

```
 Projectmainfolder->
          SourceCodeFolder
          AnotherFolder
```

I have my all code files in sourceCodeFolder, and now I want to get or print Projectmainfolder path, Kindly let me know if there is a way to get the location path of the root project folder.

Comment: What are `main project working directory` and `root project folder`? Are they the same as `Projectmainfolder`? If so, you need to be more accurate in describing your situation. If not, you need to make your question clearer.

Comment: Yes main project working directory and projectmainfolder are same. I just want to get projectmainfolder path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will give you the path to the current file.

```
__FILE__
```

In order to expand a relative path, do this:

```
File.expand_path("../../", __FILE__)
```

Comment: But how to get `Projectmainfolder`, cause it seems that's what he wants?

Comment: Thanks a ton, "File.expand_path("../../", __File__)" worked exactly I wanted.

Comment: @Chris.Zou Oops, that is a crucial point. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @sawa I just deleted my comment since you've updated your answer.:-)

Answer (score 1):

if you start your script from the `Projectmainfolder` directory, `Dir.getwd` should print you the path you want. Or did you mean something different?

Comment: This will give you the current directory of the terminal where you called the command from. Not the directory of the file.